# Formatting questions

Tags: discussion

I f I use Word to create a question (i.e. using set theory symbols or the like), will the formatting be preserved when the question is posted? I find it very hard to read most of the questions posted because of the wacky formatting.

Comment: Word does create a lot of wacky formatting

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is, Oliver. Do you mind expanding it a bit?

Comment: Not with math, unless you write up LaTeX in Word (assuming the SE supports MathJax). And that's always tough because you probably won't be able to see a preview.

Answer (score 1):

No, copy-pasting text with formulas from Word into a question on SE is  bad idea. You should invest some time into learning the syntax used for typesetting formulas on  SE sites (such as Mathematics, where you already posted some questions with subpar formatting).

Recommended reference: **[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)**